# UITableView applying changes done to every nth cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a TableView setup with different sections and items in it.

[image]

When I select a cell an image is unhidden.

[image]

However it does not just do this to one cell, it does it to every 8th in this case. In a different project, this number was every tenth.

[image]

[image]

Anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

```
import UIKit
struct Section {
    let letter : String
    let names : [String]
}
var sections = [Section]()
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {
    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    var data = ["Alb","bim","ck","Da","Esel","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","spacko","yarr","mom","nun","loser","zebra","jao","ihr","peep","reee","vogel","xylo","uuuf","tiiii","qqqq","m","z","aw","bim","ce","did","Esel","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","fried","spacko","yarrack","mom","nun","loser","zebra","jao","ihr","peep","reee","vogel","xylo","uuuf","tiiii","qqqq","m","z"]
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].names.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section].letter
    }
    func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return sections.map{$0.letter}
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.rowHeight = 90.0
        let groupedDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: data, by: {String($0.prefix(1))})
        let keys = groupedDictionary.keys.sorted()
        sections = keys.map{ Section(letter: $0, names: groupedDictionary[$0]!.sorted()) }
        table.reloadData()
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.checkmark.isHidden = !cell.checkmark.isHidden
    }
}
```

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var checkmark: UIImageView!

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cells are re-used as your scroll.  You need to ensure that `cellForRowAt` correctly configures the dequeued cell based on the data model; ie. if the `row` is selected then show the checkmark. If it isn't selected, hide it.

Since your `cellForRowAt` is essentially empty the cell displays exactly as it did the last time it was used for a row.

You could use a set to track selected rows and check its contents when configuring the cell:

```
var selectedRows = Set<IndexPath>()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.checkmark.isHidden = !self.selectedRows.contains(indexPath)
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if self.selectedRows.contains(indexPath) {
        self.selectedRows.remove(indexPath)
    } else {
        self.selectedRows.insert(indexPath)
    }
    tableView.reloadRows(at:[indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create an array of array in which store the bool values for the rows in the index depending on the rows and section and when you make the change in any of the rows in any of the section then change the bool values for that specific row in the spoecific section that you can detect in didselect row at where you can get that in which section which cell didselect has work and after that reload the specific row or the table and set values according to the array of array created.